# Image isn't appearing on image upload

Tags: php

I am using xampp on Windows 7. My problem is that the image isn't appearing when I clicked the submit button.

Here's my php code:

```
<?php

$fileLocation = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\images';
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$tempName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$size = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
$fileType = $_FILES["file"]["type"];

if ($fileType == "images/jpeg" && $size < 2000000)
{
    if ($_FILES['file']['error'] > 0)
    {
       echo "File error! : " . $_FILES['file']['error']. "</br>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "File Name: " . $name . "</br>";
    echo "File Type: " . $fileType . "</br>";
    echo "File Size: " . $size . "</br>";
    }   
        if (file_exists($file_location, $name))
            {
                echo "File already exists!" . $name . "</br>";
            }
        else 
            {
                move_uploaded_file($tempname, $fileLocation.$name);
                echo "Stored in: " . $fileLocation . "</br>";
            }
}
 ?>
```

HTML CODE:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadFile.php" method="POST">
Send this file: <input name="file" type="file" id='file'/>
<input type="submit" value="Send File" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Where is your $_POST condition ?

Comment: How far do you get and what's the last message returned? Have you checked directory permissions on the destination folder  `$fileLocation`?

Comment: @SagarPanchal> It is on another file.
@SaschaM78> I got nothing. The page was blank.

Comment: Could you `print_r($_POST);` above your file variable declarations? and display the results

Answer (score 2):

Also, check if Your HTML form has `enctype='multipart/form-data'` attribute set. It's easy to forget about it (at least I do almost every time).